# Ruby prob with File.dirname(__FILE__) and class inherance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the parent class in
/dir1/test1.rb
then i have the child class in
/dir2/test2.rb

the test1 class has a method that uses the "File.dirname(**FILE**)".
BUT when i call this method from the test2, that inherent from test1
the dir is the dir1, insted the dir2, where the test2 is.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the use of `__FILE__` has to be in test2.rb

It's really that simple. How about this?

```
class Test2
  def self.here
    @here ||= File.dirname(__FILE__)
  end
end
```

Then in the method in test1 you call self.here

Comment: the problem is that im repeating too much, imagine i have 100 child classes, and then each one should have that here method... it hurts and is not DRY :S there is not a better solution?

Comment: @Totty, please see my answer. It will work if you have a method that's already in every child class, like `initialize`.

Comment: I cannot confirm anything right now, because I no longer use ruby for years.. But thanks for your answer anyway..

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hacky but if you have a method that is already in every child class, like `def initialize` then you can do this from within an instance method in the parent class:

```
self.class.instance_method(:initialize).source_location[0]
```

Or from within a class method of the parent class:

```
self.instance_method(:initialize).source_location[0]
```

This will return the location of the file where the method is defined (eg. `/dir2/test2.rb`).